# CRC32 CRC peripheral on STM 32 : byte and word streams of same data give different results

Tags: byte, stm32, cpu-word, crc32

I am using the STM32 ARM CRC peripheral and getting different CRC codes for the same data when fed in as bytes compared to when fed in as words.

Using the byte word length and a small word aligned data string:

```
 const char *ts4 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog."; // 52 CHARS divisible by 4;
```

This, with a buffer size of `strlen(ts4)` gives a CRC32 of ~ 0x01fba559
0xfe045aa6.

It was then configured the CRC for WORD size (setting buffer size to `strlen(ts4)/4`) and the DMA engine was pointed at the CRC data register. It gave a different CRC result, ~ 0xf2bd1910 0x0d42e6ef, so I called it, again for WORD size using the HAL_CALCULATE method (to ensure the DMA was working as expected). This again gave ~ 0xf2bd1910 0x0d42e6ef.

Does the CRC32 algorithm give different results for different word size inputs ? I don't really want to tie the DMA engine up transferring bytes. Is there an equivalent `C' function that calculates CRC32 with a 32 bit WORD input ? I have tried reversing the order of the bytes in the word but this does not solve it (I thought it might have been a big/little endian problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's 51 characters, not 52. That length over 4 would give 12, not 13. The CRC of the first 48 characters would be expected to be different than the CRC of the 51 characters.

Also I'd think that you would need to assure that the string starts on a word boundary.

Comment: YUP! It all works now! Added a '.' to the end and they match. Thankyou. I now have full speed 32 bit DMA'd CRCs..... (bit new here... should I delete this thread)... it does kind of prove the BYTE and WORD CRC32 peripheral in the ARM should give the same results though.

Comment: Dear user50619, I have exactly your problem and get exactly your result(0xf2bd1910). Please can you explain better how do you solved? Do I have to use HAL_Calculate before HAL_Accumulate? I think I tried everythings and i'm sure there is something that I don't understand.

Comment: @Superfra https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Comment: @MarkAdler :) :) :) very nice! Thanks anyway!